# ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I am using [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) gem to display chart. I have followed the proper installation documentation but whenever I am trying to use their methods like

```
timeline [["Washington", "1789-04-29", "1797-03-03"], ["Adams", "1797-03-03", "1801-03-03"], ["Jefferson", "1801-03-03", "1809-03-03"]]
```

It's showing error in the firebug
**ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined**

Comment: Did you put `//= require chartkick` in your `application.js`?

Comment: @fivedigit yes i have added the same

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which charting library you prefer, you need to include it's javascript path in your view file. That solved the issue for me.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "path/to/highcharts.js", "chartkick" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets walk through all potential pitfalls (non-highcharts solution)

---

GEMFILE:

make sure to run bundle install afterwards

```
include 'chartkick'
```

---

APPLICATION.JS:

in your `config/environments/development.rb` you might have set `config.assets.compress = true` and `config.assets.compile = true` and `config.serve_static_files = true`, which would mean you would need to recompile your assets to see changes in development.

```
//= require chartkick
```

---

HAML:

javascript include line begins '=' not '-'. @report.data should be active record relation

```
= javascript_include_tag '//www.google.com/jsapi', 'chartkick'
= pie_chart @report.data
```

---

SERVER:

If using spring, try `spring stop`. Restart your rails server. Force reload page `cmd+shift+R` or `ctrl+shift+R` (not all browsers can do this)

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

including:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= yield :charts_js %>
```

in application.html.erb + following the documentation steps

as per https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/499

Answer (score 0):

I'd verify that everything's in place per:

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/3

And:

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/1

Comment: I have checked the same but the issue remains same